# Could you tell me why the author need to wrap FrameLayout for Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Code A is from [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml). and it's a part of [sample project](https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic).

I don't know why the author need to wrap *FrameLayout* for *Fragment*,
after I remove the *FrameLayout* of Code A and get Code B, and Code B works well.

Could you tell me why the author need to wrap FrameLayout for Fragment?

**Code A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Code B**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

Comment: maybe just for `android:keepScreenOn` ?

Comment: @HelloCW Code B is pretty enough for a NavHost.

Answer (score 4):

> Could you tell me why the author need to wrap FrameLayout for Fragment?

That `FrameLayout` is not needed. It is possible that the `FrameLayout` was originally there for other reasons (e.g., changing contents via `FragmentTransaction`) and was never removed.